# Date/Time format issue with Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, handlebars.js

I get the date/time value as below in JSON:

```
"ChangedDate":"\/Date(1349469145000)\/"
```

In FF and IE, I get the above date in 12 hr format (10/5/2012 - 3:32:25 PM) using the helper function below:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('FormatDate', function (date) {
            if (date == null)
                return "";
            else {
                var value = new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));
                return value.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + value.getDate() + "/" + value.getFullYear() + " - " + value.toLocaleTimeString();
            }
        });
```

however, in Chrome I still get the 24 hr format (10/5/2012 - 15:32:25).

How do I get the date/time value in 12 hr format in Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use [toLocaleTimeString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) when the intent is to display to the user a
>   string formatted using the regional format chosen by the user. Be
>   aware that this method, due to its nature, behaves differently
>   depending on the operating system and on the user's settings.

You may be better off changing this line:

```
return value.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + value.getDate() + "/" + value.getFullYear() + " - " + value.toLocaleTimeString();
```

to:

```
return value.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + value.getDate() + "/" + value.getFullYear() + " - " + (value.getHours() > 12 ? value.getHours() - 12 : value.getHours()) + ":" + value.getMinutes() + ":" + value.getSeconds();
```

Where we check to see if the hours are  `> 12` and if so we subtract 12 from that number.

```
(value.getHours() > 12 ? value.getHours() - 12 : value.getHours())
```

So your example `15:32:25` would be `15 - 12 = 3`: `3:32:25`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getSeconds

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours

**EDIT**

```
//set up example
var date = new Date("10/5/2012");
date.setHours(15,32,25,00);

//Get data from date
var month = date.getMonth()+1;
var day = date.getDate();
var year = date.getFullYear();

var hours = date.getHours();
var amOrPm = "AM";
if(date.getHours() > 12){
    hours = date.getHours() - 12;
    amOrPm = "PM";
}

var minutes = date.getMinutes();
if(minutes  < 10)
    minutes = "0" + minutes;

var seconds = date.getSeconds();
if(seconds < 10)
    seconds = "0" + seconds;

var dateString = month + "/" + day + "/" + year + " - " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

console.log(dateString);
```

I made this example a bit more detailed than needed, but it helps to show you what's going on. Hope it helps.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hrfvk/)**

Condensed down this would look something like:

```
//Get data from date
var dateString = (date.getMonth()+1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" +  date.getFullYear() + " - " + (date.getHours() > 12 ? date.getHours() - 12 : date.getHours())+ ":" + (date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes()) + ":" + (date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds()) + " " + (date.getHours() > 12 ? "PM" : "AM");
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hrfvk/1/)**

Comment: Thanks. But then how do I add the am/pm values and show the values in two digit format (01 in place of 1 in minutes)?

Comment: I'll make a js fiddle here shortly to show you, but its basically the same concept as above. You would check to see if the minutes are less than 10, if so then you pre-pend a `0`. am/pm is dependent on the hours, so if it's `> 12`, it's pm, otherwise it's am.

Comment: Let me know if that's what you're looking for and if not I'll be more than happy to help you out more. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had a add a condition for handling the hour value 12  if (hours == 12) {
                    hours = 12 + (hours % 12);
                    amOrPm = "PM";
                }

Comment: Other than that is it perfect and exactly what I was looking for.